# How to install additional perl module on latest perl (Active state)

Tags: perl, installation-package

I've just installed Perl 5.26 x64 under Windows 10.

The command below causes an error:

```perl
perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

Error is: Can't located `Win32::Console`

Please help

Comment: Try running `cpan Win32::Console` before running `perl -MCPAN -e shell`.

Comment: Or `ppm install Win32-Console` since you said you're using ActiveState

Comment: hmmm, doesn't Win32::Console come with ActivePerl?

Comment: (And I seriously doubt the message you got was "`Can't located Win32::Console`")

Comment: Try running cpan Win32::Console - I did - it show same error

Comment: ppm install Win32-Console - can not find ppm - it does not come with v.5.26 - but I did use it in previous version of Perl. Now it is gone...

Comment: Win32::Console come with ActivePerl - It should come - but since I've installed Perl x64 - probably it should not use win32?

Comment: Exact error message is Can't locate Win32::Console.pm (you may need to install win32::Console.pm) But how to install it ?

Comment: Try running just 'cpan', since it is first insatallation it wil install 'MimGW' and other thing. After than install any module

Comment: See also [ppm doesn't work after installing ActiveState Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58538495/2173773)

Answer (score 7):

Had same problem, i installed [strawberry perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) and worked perfectly

Comment: This is because, strawberry perl already contains Win32 module in it. Download link -   http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem, solved by commenting lines 395-413 with # in
c:\Perl64\site\lib\ActivePerl\Config.pm
They are lines in function _warn under line
# Prevent calling Win32::Console::DESTROY on a STDOUT handle
I have found this solution on https://www.programmersought.com/article/93215566461/