# ppm doesn't work after installing ActiveState Perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to install OpenSSL for a mongodb example, but can't install some perl packages

I installed ActivePerl 5.28, restarted the computer, added path variable, and ppm still doesn't work

[image: PathVariables]

When i type ppm into cmd it returns

```
'ppm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Cpan works but I can't install some packages like dmake

[image: dmakeCmd]

Comment: I tried to install ActivePerl 5.28 on a Windows 10 laptop now. I chose the typical setup type (not the custom or complete options). After the installer completed I opened the Command Prompt window and typed `ppm`, and got the same error as you got: `'ppm' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like you need to add the `ActivePerl-PPM` package to the Active Platform perl project before downloading the installer `.exe`.

- First, remove the old installation of ActivePerl (I am not sure if this is necessary though). Double-Click the installer `.exe`, typically something like: `ActivePerl-5.28.1.0000-MSWin32-x64-832ee6ab.exe`, then click "Next" and then click "Remove".
- Now, go to the Active Platform page of the forked perl project:
  https://platform.activestate.com
- Click the configuration tab of the project and click "Add packages"
- Add the package "ActivePerl-PPM", click "Add" and then "Done".
- Still in the configuration tab, click "Commit changes"
- From the "Overview" tab, click the download button for the new build.

After installing the new build, I get the following output from the Command Prompt:

```
C:\Users\Bruker>ppm
ppm gui failed: Can't locate Win32/OLE.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Win32::OLE module) (@INC contains: C:/Perl64/lib C:/Perl64/site/lib)
```

So at least now it finds the `ppm` executable, but there are still missing modules.

**Edit**:

After also adding two more packages to the build: `Win32-Console`, and `Win32-OLE`. Then rebuilding and reinstalling, the `ppm` command finally worked:

[image]

The command `cpan dmake` still fails though, see also [How to install dmake with perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56972534/2173773)

Comment: Like you said ppm works now but dmake still doesn't work. Think I'll just give up and get another OpenSSL client

Comment: Ok, but I think it would be nice to dig a little bit more here. Which packages are you now not able to install? I can have a try at it if you tell me where to start?